# How can I display `₹` properly in pdf in Magento.?

Tags: php, magento, pdf

`Indian Rupee symbol(₹)` is not displaying in invoice **pdf** in `magento`.
In **system->manage currency->symbols** I `save currency symbol` as `₹`.

Then the pdf looks:

[image]

I change symbol in **system->manage currency->symbols** to  `&#8377;`

Then the pdf looks like this:

[image]

How can I display `₹` properly in `pdf`(invoice,order etc) in `Magento`.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*r4ven*'s and *rajatsaurastri*'s answers helped me to find the solution. Thank you very much guys..

However I post the answer that make it working well..

1.Download the font that support Indian Rupee symbol. I download `dejavu-sans` font.

2.place the font in `lib` directory.

3.open **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php** and **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php**

and  replace

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf');
```

with

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf');
```

(in `_setFontRegular()`, `_setFontBold()`, `_setFontItalic()` functions in both files.)

This [**link**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf) gives more info about changing the font.

Comment: please do not modify core files override it otherwise after update you will loose your changes

Answer (score 2):

can you check your local.xml file inside app/etc what charset is there if not then try with adding charset

```
<charset>utf8</charset>
```

Comment: where to add <charset>utf8</charset> in local.xml. I fear that any change in local.xml results the reinstallation of magento.

Comment: in your local.xml you will find your db configuration as <default_setup<connection></default_setup</connection>. Add it in between these tags

Answer (score 2):

You need to use font for your pdf that include Indian Rupee symbol

Comment: [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf) you have infos about tweaking pdf in magneto

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for Magento2.1.

we need to extend *Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice* this.We can't override *AbstractPdf.php* directly.

I have created one module for this.You can take download from [here](https://github.com/gunjali-agarwal/magento).Its working properly.